# How to enable or disable the element attribute to true/false in puppeteer

Tags: jquery, puppeteer

i want to enable the element using jQuery don't know how to implement in puppeteer but it's giving an error `Property 'attr' does not exist on type 'Promise<ElementHandle<Element>>'.`

Here is my code:

```js
await page.$('[name=creditCardNumber],[name=cvv]').attr('disabled',false);
```

this is the jQuery i need to execute

```js
$('[name=creditCardNumber],[name=cvv]').attr('disabled',false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

`page.$('[name=creditCardNumber],[name=cvv]')` returns a Promise which you first need to await before you can call a function (like `attr` on it).

There is also another problem: The function `attr` is a jQuery function, which is not available on an `ElementHandle` in puppeteer.

#### Fix

You can select the node and then set `disabled` to `false` (without jQuery) with the function [`page.$eval`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1). The function first queries a node and then executes the function on it.

```js
await page.$eval('[name=creditCardNumber],[name=cvv]', el => el.disabled = false);
```